# Is it safe to call a throwing function inside a catch block?

Tags: javascript

```
exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, _context) => {
    const email = data.email;
    const password = data.password;

    try {
        // First, create the user account.
        const userRecord = await admin.auth().createUser({
            email: email,
            password: password,
        });

        // User successfully created, now update the database.
        const userId = userRecord.uid;
        const db = admin.firestore();
        const batch = db.batch();
        batch.create(
            db.collection("userAccounts").doc(userId), {created: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()},
        );
        await batch.commit();

        // Database successfully updated, now return the newly-created userId.
        return Promise.resolve(userId);
    } catch (error) {
        if (userId) {
            // There was an error updating the database. However, a user was created
            // beforehand. Therefore, delete the user before terminating the
            // function.
            admin.auth().deleteUser(userId); // <-- this throws
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unknown", "Database error", error);
        }
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unknown", "Authentication error", error);
    }
});
```

This function performs two async tasks: creates a user and updates a database. If the database update fails, I need to undelete the user. This function deletes the user in the catch block when it catches a database error. However, deleting the user itself throws. If the delete-user function fails, would that error be caught in this catch block and possibly create an infinite loop? How best to handle this scenario?

Comment: `If the delete-user function fails, would that error be caught in this catch block and possibly create an infinite loop?` No. Thats what `try` does, not `catch`.

Comment: @tkausl is the error even caught at all? Would it need its own `try-catch` block nested inside the current one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not create an infinite loop, but the error won't be caught either - which should be avoided. You'll need to tack on another `.catch`, because you also want to throw a different error afterwards.

```
} catch (error) {
    if (userId) {
        // There was an error updating the database. However, a user was created
        // beforehand. Therefore, delete the user before terminating the
        // function.
        admin.auth().deleteUser(userId)
            .catch(() => {}); // Ignore errors thrown by deleteUser
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unknown", "Database error", error);
    }
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unknown", "Authentication error", error);
}
```

You should also be sure that the caller of this callback passed to `onCall` catches its asynchronous errors to avoid unhandled rejections.

Still, this process is pretty suspect - it seems odd to be deliberately calling a function you think will probably throw. If you need to call `deleteUser` only in the case that `createUser` succeeds, checking for the `userId` looks like the right approach, but that'll only work if the variable is in scope at that point, which it isn't. You can change your code to:

```
exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, _context) => {
    const { email, password } = data;
    let userId; // <---------------------------
    try {
        // First, create the user account.
        const userRecord = await admin.auth().createUser({ email, password });

        // User successfully created, now update the database.
        userId = userRecord.uid; // <---------------------------
        const db = admin.firestore();
        const batch = db.batch();
        batch.create(
            db.collection("userAccounts").doc(userId), {created: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()},
        );
        await batch.commit();

        // Database successfully updated, now return the newly-created userId.
        return userId; // don't need to wrap this in a Promise
    } catch (error) {
        if (userId) {
            // There was an error updating the database. However, a user was created
            // beforehand. Therefore, delete the user before terminating the
            // function.
            admin.auth().deleteUser(userId)
                .catch(() => {}); // This SHOULDN'T throw, but just in case
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unknown", "Database error", error);
        }
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unknown", "Authentication error", error);
    }
});
```

Or to

```
exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, _context) => {
    const { email, password } = data;
    let userId;
    try {
        // First, create the user account.
        const userRecord = await admin.auth().createUser({ email, password });
        userId = userRecord.uid;
    } catch (error) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unknown", "Authentication error", error);
    }
    try {
        // User successfully created, now update the database.
        const db = admin.firestore();
        const batch = db.batch();
        batch.create(
            db.collection("userAccounts").doc(userId), { created: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() },
        );
        await batch.commit();

        // Database successfully updated, now return the newly-created userId.
        return userId;
    } catch (error) {
        // There was an error updating the database. However, a user was created
        // beforehand. Therefore, delete the user before terminating the
        // function.
        admin.auth().deleteUser(userId);
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unknown", "Database error", error);
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't know how else to approach this. If the user is created but the database doesn't reflect it, my only 2 options are to retry the database update (which may fail again) or delete the user (which also may fail but I would expect it not to since `createUser` succeeded). If you have any input or opinion on this overall task I would love to hear it.

Comment: Ah, I see the point of it now. Yeah, I suppose you could separate out the lines so that `deleteUser` is called only in the case that the line that puts the user in the database is run (not sure which line that is though, I'm not familiar with firestore).

Comment: Could you kindly edit your answer to include how to handle the error thrown by `deleteUser` instead of just ignoring it? Just so I know the proper syntax. Thank you!

Comment: I'm uncertain because I don't know which line it is that `deleteUser` is intended to revert - is it `createUser` (sounds likely, but I dunno)? `batch.commit`?

Comment: `deleteUser` is intended to undo `createUser`. I just want to be sure of the syntax and how to properly handle the `error` in this new catch statement you added.

Comment: See edit - make sure that `userId` is in scope, or use two `try`/`catch`s to distinguish whether `.createUser` succeeded or not